# How can I catch and handle a signal in Perl?

Tags: perl, signals

Is there any way to trap an error and exit gracefully from Perl? I am working on a script which might fail due to a SIG event from the OS or other applications running on my server. I wish to trap this event, display the error and exit after closing all files and other attributes I have open during the execution of the script.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the %SIG hash to install signal handlers.  Example:

$SIG{INT} = 'SigIntHandler';

Where SigIntHandler is a sub that you write to be called when an interrupt is caught.

Comment: does %SIG require any standard library to be used?

Answer (score 6):

See [perldoc sigtrap](http://www.perl.com/doc/manual/html/lib/sigtrap.html).

Comment: thanks will look up the doc for this. although was getting a bit confused with the same... could you give an example for how this can be handled?